# How to provide website access permission in webview when publish app to playstore?

Tags: android, webview, publish

Hi Friends i developed website to mobile app. my app is basically display the website into webview.i publish my android app in playsore. after publishing  my app is suspended due to website access permission.I am the authorized person for access that website.but i don't know how to give website authentication permission in my app.please give me a answer friend

Comment: Posting the exact error message that Play Store Developer Console is showing while publishing would be helpful to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> ::Posting the suspension message would be of help

Most beginners in Android make apps directing to a website (that they do not own) and publish it to get downloads. You will need to show Google that the website is yours.